# How to get plural label of a standard object inside salesforce lightning component?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

In visualforce page we could access plural labels by writing `{!$ObjectType.Opportunity.labelPlural}` but in lightning it does not seem to support that. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `$ObjectType` isn't available in Lightning.
You can find Lightning Global Value Providers [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_source.htm).

For your use case, you will need to [call a server-side Apex Method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm) which will use [getLabelPlural()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_getLabelPlural) from [DescribeSObjectResult Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm) to get you what you need.